# How can I reconstruct a QM probability curve using a truncated cos curve?

Tags: calculus, analysis, algorithms

I have a curve that represents a quantum mechanical probability.  I am interested in finding an algorithm (or calc I/II type formula) to compute a weighting function, k(), that will reconstruct this curve using truncated cos(). I don't think this is Fourier problem ...

The reconstruction is to study the how quantum probabilities might be represented by coupled classical rotational motion.

The curve itself, f(x)^2, takes two parameters $k_1 , k_2$ as arbitrary inputs, but all other constants are calculated from them.

$f(x)^2=(A cos(k_1 x) + B sin(k_1 x))^2$ for x<0
$f(x)^2=(C cos(k_2 x) + D sin(k_2 x))^2$ for x>=0

Where:

$B={1 \over \sqrt{ k_2 + k_1 }}$

$A=\sqrt{1-B^2}$

$C=A$

$D={k_1 \over k_2} B$

f(x)^2 is defined over $[x_1:x_2]$

$x_1 = {atan(-{A \over B}) \over k_1}$,

$x_2 = {atan(-{C \over D}) + \pi) \over k_2}$

The way I need to reconstruct $f(x)^2$ is by the following summation of truncated cos functions:

$isubpx(x)=scale \cdot \Sigma_{n=1}^{1000} cos_t(2 k(X_n)(x-X_n)) $

Where:

$X_n=x_1+{\pi \over {4 k_1}} + (x_2-x_1-{\pi \over {4 k_1}} - {\pi \over {4 k_2}}){n \over 1000} $

$cos_t(x) = cos(x)$  for $-{\pi \over 2} < x < {\pi \over 2}$

$cos_t(x) = 0 $    elsewhere.

$scale \approx 0.01822385 \cdot k_1$

Note:
If constant $k_1=k_2$, then the k() function becomes constant over x.  In general, the k() function will likely start at $k_1$ and end at $k_2$

As an example, if I choose $k_1=2$ and $k_2=1$, the following plot shows the function (in purple), and it shows my first attempted weighting function (in blue), and the sum of the 1000 localized cosine functions in green.

[image: CURVE and attempted reconstruction]

The associated cos() function's width is set by the blue line's height; 1/k() -- so the blue line's height measures the area each cos() will add to the green curve.